# Best way to call web services?

Tags: android, api, web-services, httprequest

I'm developing android application which call web services via asyncTask.

The problem is almost in each activity I'm creating asynctask and calling a web service in it.In some activity the code is almost the same and it calls the same web service the only difference is in the Onpost method cause the action that I want to take is differ based on the activity.

What I want to do is having a separate class or activity that contains all the calling to the web service but I don't know how to do it. How to change the content of the onPost based on the activity that calls this web service?

It sounds like a dumb question but any idea would help and would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use retrofit library for calling your services it's best lib https://square.github.io/retrofit/ and create a class with name like NetworkHandler using  singleton pattern all you network staff place class.

Comment: Advantage is you never need write same code again and again just write it once and use overall app using singleton.

Comment: @AnasMehar thank you so much Anas! much appreciated. I will search about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. I normally use [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to make calls, then:

- create one class with all calls, say CallerClass,
- create an interface to listen for results from CallerClass, say CallerClassListener
- initialize CallerClass from an Application Class
  this way, I can get the CallerClass instance from any activity or class.
  I know my explanation isn't the best but see [here](https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-1-network-error-handling-response-caching-77483cf68620) for a complete implementation

**Update**
Providing code for the explanation above, you could visit [here](https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-1-network-error-handling-response-caching-77483cf68620)

You could use an application class, say AppNameApp:

```
public class AppNameApp extends Application {
private ApiService apiService;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public ApiService getApiService() {
    if (apiService == null) {
        apiService = 
provideRetrofit(ApiService.URL).create(ApiService.class);
    }
    return apiService;
}

private Retrofit provideRetrofit(String url) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .client(provideOkHttpClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
            .build();
}

private OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okhttpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okhttpClientBuilder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okhttpClientBuilder.writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return okhttpClientBuilder.build();
}
}
```

then do an interface, say ApiService:

```
public interface ApiService {
String URL = "https://api.example.com" + "/v1/";

@GET("accounts/{accountId}")
    Call<AccountInfo> getAccountInfo(@Path("accountId") String accountId);
}
```

finally, you can call the interface from any activity, say HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}

private void getAccountInfo() {
 ((App) getApplication()).getApiService().getAccountInfo()
      .enqueue(new Callback<AccountInfo>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<AccountInfo> call, 
   Response<AccountInfo> response) {
              if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                  // return to UI thread
                  // display AccountInfo on UI
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<AccountInfo> call, Throwable t) {
              // skip for now
          }
      });
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Augustus , could you share with me that part? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: WOW!!! This is exactly what I wanted!! many thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help.